# TabWidget problem

Tags: android, dictionary, tabs, activity-lifecycle

so I know that the TabWidget does not create new activities on each tab click. But I am confused.. if I have a tab activity that contains a map, and if some values change from some other tab that are linked with the map activity and it should (for my needs) draw something on the map with those changed values taken into account. How can I do that?
Because on the tab click the onCreate method from the map activity won't be called. I can only exit the app, then enter again, and then it works like I want to. Can onDraw be called from the other activity or sth.. If someone knows how to resolve my problem, please let me know. Thank u, in advance.

Comment: See Berdon's comment of using `onResume()`. The `onCreate()` method of an Activity can often be very minimal with a lot more code handling 'dynamic' changes being better placed in `onResume()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of options:

1. Use [onResume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29)
2. Broadcast intents to your other activity and use a [Broadcast Receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)
3. You could even use a static class to store information that is accessible between the two.

I would use option 1. :)